# Binary logistic regression - do i have to perform tests like in multiple regression?

Tags: regression, logistic

I am a beginner here. I would like to ask if i run binary logistic regression, do i have to do the tests below just like in multiple regression?
(1) stationarity of data
(2) multicollinearity
(3) autocorrelation
(4) heteroskedasticity
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Are these time-series data? If so, standard logistic regression might not be appropriate and you might want to consider some form of survival or recurrent-event analysis.

Comment: Hi! yes it is time-series data

Answer (score 1):

No.  Logistic regression makes no assumption about the probability distribution of the input features(variables), so you can have skewness, non-normality, etc. among your features.  Logistic regression is also not a linear method, and in fact is based on logarithms -- so it's multiplicative, i.e. based on log(x), exp(x).  Make sure there are not more features than records, i.e., $p \gg n$, or the program you're using will drop features due to singularity issues.

Comment: thank you so much! may i ask further about the X variables to be included in the logistic regression? i plan to use financial ratios which are all numbers and i'm not sure that in logistic regression, how to select most-fitted X variable. is it the same as multiple regression where you select model based on AIC, R^2?

Comment: Yes, you can use ratio-type variables as predictors.  Goodness-of-fit of a logistic model is usually based on a chi-square statistic, resulting from a log-likelihood ratio test.  There should be a chi-squared test in the output, with a certain degrees of freedom ("d.f.") related to the number of predictors in the model.  If the P-value for the chi-squared test is P<0.05, then the model fits.

Answer (score 1):

Logistic multiple regression is conceptually similar to standard multiple regression, so you do have to evaluate many of the same quality-control metrics in either case, particularly with respect to the predictor variables. The difference is that in logistic regression you are trying to use a linear combination of the predictors to estimate the log-odds of the probability of an event, rather than an observed continuous response variable. As the observations are simply whether the event happened or not, you find values of the regression coefficients that maximize the likelihood of observing the yes/no outcome data through an iterative process. In standard multiple regression, the least-squares criterion gives effectively a one-step answer to the same optimization. The [Brier score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score), often used to evaluate the goodness-of-fit of logistic regression, is effectively the mean-square error around the predictions.

In an application to time-series data, however, logistic regression might not be the best choice for a yes/no outcome. Survival analysis, or the related recurrent-event analysis if the same event can happen to an individual at multiple times, may be much more useful as it also includes information about times to events and not just whether an event happened. In survival analysis there are standard ways to account for intra-individual correlations in event probabilities (clustering, frailty analysis) that would otherwise appear as auto-correlations. Depending on the structure of your data and your understanding of the subject matter, survival analysis could be preferable to logistic regression.